# MAAS - Internal server error by selecting "Settings" tab

Tags: server, juju, maas, log, webserver

When I click on Settings on MAAS Web UI,

[image]

I encountering the message `Internal server error.`[image]

I can't figure out why I'm encountering this message ONLY by clicking on settings tab, and to be honest I can't provide a time laps when it stopped at least to have a point to work on a solution.

I've `sudo apt-get updated` system, restarted and rebooted several times, googled as well around, but couldn't find anything useful.

As you may see from MAAS log (`cat /var/log/maas/maas.log`), there's nothing about this issue:

```
May 21 06:29:38 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 06:29:39 regionA maas.bootsources: [info] Updated boot sources cache.
May 21 06:29:39 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Started importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 06:29:39 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 06:29:40 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Importing images from source: http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 06:29:46 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Finished importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 07:29:38 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 07:29:39 regionA maas.bootsources: [info] Updated boot sources cache.
May 21 07:29:39 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Started importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 07:29:39 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 07:29:40 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Importing images from source: http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 07:29:46 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Finished importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 08:29:38 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 08:29:39 regionA maas.bootsources: [info] Updated boot sources cache.
May 21 08:29:39 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Started importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 08:29:39 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 08:29:40 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Importing images from source: http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 08:29:46 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Finished importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 09:29:38 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 09:29:39 regionA maas.bootsources: [info] Updated boot sources cache.
May 21 09:29:39 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Started importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 09:29:39 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 09:29:40 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Importing images from source: http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 09:29:46 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Finished importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 10:29:38 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 10:29:40 regionA maas.bootsources: [info] Updated boot sources cache.
May 21 10:29:40 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Started importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 10:29:40 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 10:29:40 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Importing images from source: http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 10:29:46 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Finished importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 11:29:38 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 11:29:39 regionA maas.bootsources: [info] Updated boot sources cache.
May 21 11:29:39 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Started importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 11:29:39 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 11:29:40 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Importing images from source: http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 11:29:46 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Finished importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 12:29:38 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 12:29:39 regionA maas.bootsources: [info] Updated boot sources cache.
May 21 12:29:39 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Started importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 12:29:39 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 12:29:40 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Importing images from source: http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 12:29:46 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Finished importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 13:29:38 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 13:29:39 regionA maas.bootsources: [info] Updated boot sources cache.
May 21 13:29:39 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Started importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 13:29:39 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 13:29:40 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Importing images from source: http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 13:29:46 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Finished importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 14:29:38 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 14:29:39 regionA maas.bootsources: [info] Updated boot sources cache.
May 21 14:29:39 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Started importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 14:29:39 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 14:29:40 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Importing images from source: http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 14:29:46 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Finished importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 15:29:38 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 15:29:40 regionA maas.bootsources: [info] Updated boot sources cache.
May 21 15:29:40 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Started importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 15:29:40 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 15:29:40 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Importing images from source: http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 15:29:46 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Finished importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 16:29:10 regionA maas.networks.monitor: [info] Networks monitoring service: Process ID 1458 assumed responsibility.
May 21 16:29:12 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 16:29:14 regionA maas.refresh: [info] Refreshing rack controller hardware information.
May 21 16:29:15 regionA maas.bootsources: [info] Updated boot sources cache.
May 21 16:29:15 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Started importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 16:29:15 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 16:29:15 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Importing images from source: http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 16:29:19 regionA maas.node: [info] regionA: Storage layout was set to flat.
May 21 16:29:21 regionA maas.rpc.rackcontrollers: [info] Existing rack controller 'rackA' has connected to region 'regionA'.
May 21 16:29:22 regionA maas.rpc.rackcontrollers: [info] Existing rack controller 'rackA' has connected to region 'regionA'.
May 21 16:29:24 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Finished importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 17:29:10 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 17:29:11 regionA maas.bootsources: [info] Updated boot sources cache.
May 21 17:29:11 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Started importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 17:29:11 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 17:29:12 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Importing images from source: http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 17:29:18 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Finished importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 17:56:10 regionA maas.mDNS: [info] eno1 (physical) on rackA: Hostname 'modularcodes-MBP' moved from fe80::1cc4:46da:a9ea:7cbb to fe80::10b6:4a3:179e:19bf.
May 21 18:18:25 regionA maas.node: [info] nodeA02: Status transition from FAILED_COMMISSIONING to COMMISSIONING
May 21 18:18:25 regionA maas.node: [info] nodeA02: Commissioning started
May 21 18:21:37 regionA maas.networks.monitor: [info] Networks monitoring service: Process ID 1429 assumed responsibility.
May 21 18:21:40 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 18:21:42 regionA maas.refresh: [info] Refreshing rack controller hardware information.
May 21 18:21:43 regionA maas.bootsources: [info] Updated boot sources cache.
May 21 18:21:43 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Started importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 18:21:43 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 18:21:43 regionA maas.rpc.rackcontrollers: [info] Existing rack controller 'rackA' has connected to region 'regionA'.
May 21 18:21:44 regionA maas.rpc.rackcontrollers: [info] Existing rack controller 'rackA' has connected to region 'regionA'.
May 21 18:21:44 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Importing images from source: http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 18:21:48 regionA maas.node: [info] regionA: Storage layout was set to flat.
May 21 18:21:51 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Finished importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 18:27:42 regionA maas.interface: [info] eno1 (physical) on rackA: New MAC, IP binding observed: 30:10:b3:2c:a5:07, 192.168.1.193
May 21 18:39:37 regionA maas.node: [error] nodeA02: Marking node failed: Machine operation 'Commissioning' timed out after 20 minutes.
May 21 18:39:37 regionA maas.node: [info] nodeA02: Status transition from COMMISSIONING to FAILED_COMMISSIONING
May 21 19:21:37 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 19:21:39 regionA maas.bootsources: [info] Updated boot sources cache.
May 21 19:21:39 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Started importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 19:21:39 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 19:21:40 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Importing images from source: http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 19:21:46 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Finished importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 19:54:52 regionA maas.node: [info] nodeA02: Status transition from FAILED_COMMISSIONING to COMMISSIONING
May 21 19:54:52 regionA maas.node: [info] nodeA02: Commissioning started
May 21 19:57:16 regionA maas.node: [info] nodeA02: Status transition from COMMISSIONING to FAILED_COMMISSIONING
May 21 19:57:16 regionA maas.node: [error] nodeA02: Marking node failed: Power on for the node failed: Could not contact node's BMC: Connection timed out while performing power action.  Check BMC configuration and connectivity and try again.
May 21 19:59:19 regionA maas.node: [info] nodeA02: Status transition from FAILED_COMMISSIONING to COMMISSIONING
May 21 19:59:19 regionA maas.node: [info] nodeA02: Commissioning started
May 21 20:01:43 regionA maas.node: [info] nodeA02: Status transition from COMMISSIONING to FAILED_COMMISSIONING
May 21 20:01:43 regionA maas.node: [error] nodeA02: Marking node failed: Power on for the node failed: Could not contact node's BMC: Connection timed out while performing power action.  Check BMC configuration and connectivity and try again.
May 21 20:11:37 regionA maas.node: [info] nodeA02: Status transition from FAILED_COMMISSIONING to COMMISSIONING
May 21 20:11:37 regionA maas.node: [info] nodeA02: Commissioning started
May 21 20:14:02 regionA maas.node: [info] nodeA02: Status transition from COMMISSIONING to FAILED_COMMISSIONING
May 21 20:14:02 regionA maas.node: [error] nodeA02: Marking node failed: Power on for the node failed: Could not contact node's BMC: Connection timed out while performing power action.  Check BMC configuration and connectivity and try again.
May 21 20:14:54 regionA maas.subnet: [info] User 'admin' initiated a neighbour discovery scan against subnet: 192.168.1.0/24
May 21 20:15:58 regionA maas.node: [info] nodeA02: Status transition from FAILED_COMMISSIONING to COMMISSIONING
May 21 20:15:59 regionA maas.node: [info] nodeA02: Commissioning started
May 21 20:18:23 regionA maas.node: [info] nodeA02: Status transition from COMMISSIONING to FAILED_COMMISSIONING
May 21 20:18:23 regionA maas.node: [error] nodeA02: Marking node failed: Power on for the node failed: Could not contact node's BMC: Connection timed out while performing power action.  Check BMC configuration and connectivity and try again.
May 21 20:21:37 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 20:21:39 regionA maas.bootsources: [info] Updated boot sources cache.
May 21 20:21:39 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Started importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 20:21:39 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 20:21:40 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Importing images from source: http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 20:21:54 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Finished importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 21:21:37 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 21:21:39 regionA maas.bootsources: [info] Updated boot sources cache.
May 21 21:21:39 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Started importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 21:21:39 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 21:21:40 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Importing images from source: http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 21:21:46 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Finished importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 22:21:37 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 22:21:39 regionA maas.bootsources: [info] Updated boot sources cache.
May 21 22:21:39 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Started importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 22:21:39 regionA maas.import-images: [info] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 22:21:40 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Importing images from source: http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/daily/
May 21 22:21:46 regionA maas.bootresources: [info] Finished importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
May 21 22:35:33 regionA maas.node: [info] nodeA02: Status transition from FAILED_COMMISSIONING to COMMISSIONING
May 21 22:35:33 regionA maas.node: [info] nodeA02: Commissioning started
May 21 22:37:58 regionA maas.node: [info] nodeA02: Status transition from COMMISSIONING to FAILED_COMMISSIONING
May 21 22:37:58 regionA maas.node: [error] nodeA02: Marking node failed: Power on for the node failed: Could not contact node's BMC: Connection timed out while performing power action.  Check BMC configuration and connectivity and try again.
```

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Is this only happening for 'settings' tab? Can you share '/var/log/maas/{rackd, regiond}.log?

Comment: @Junaid unfortunately I was forced to reinstall everything on Region controller... to answer your question anyway, yes, It heppend only on the settings tab on MAAS Web UI.

Comment: I hope MAAS is working fine for you now. Btw, rackd, regiond and maas.log should give us the info for any error.

Comment: @Junaid as soon as i get back an error, I'll post these on this post. I'll keep it still open for any cases. Not to be forced to open another. :D